# Displaying ad banner in website for the first time

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am going to create kind of banner for my web page which appears only one time when users enter to my page. Is there anyone who had any guide on it. It is javascript. Thank you so much.

Comment: This is not a free code/script writing service but a question and answer site for specific programming-related issues.
Hence you have to try it on your own first, and when stuck, come back here, edit your question and provide a minimal reproducible example of your coding attempts: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please take the tour and read How to Ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Use local storage and set a flag that an user visited your site.

If the flag is not set show the ad.

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage